# Unable to generate xml results with ci_reporter using Ruby 1.9.2 with Watir

Tags: ruby, watir, ruby-1.9, testunit

I have installed Watir 1.7.1, Ruby 1.9.2, ci_reporter 1.6.4, test unit 2.2.0.

Since testunit donot come with Ruby 1.9.2, I installed the testunit seperately.

When I run the script, ci_reporter donot create 'test/reports' folder in the directory iam running the tests. When i execute the script, script runs fine but the folder is not created.

Does the folder 'test/reports' gets created by itself or the 'test/reports' folder should be as part of testunit.

Following is the simple test iam running, please look at the code snippet :

```
gem 'test-unit'
require 'test/unit/ui/console/testrunner.rb'
require 'ci/reporter/rake/test_unit_loader.rb'
require 'watir'

class My_Test < Test::Unit::TestCase

  def test_me
    browser = Watir::IE.start('http://www.google.com')
    assert(browser.link(:text, 'About Google').exists?)
    browser.close
  end

end
```

Does ruby 1.9.2 support ci_reporter 1.6.4?

Can any one help me with an example as to how the reports would be created by ci_reporter and where the reports get stored?

Comment: When entering a code sample, please select that portion of the text and use the curly-brace ( {} ) icon to format it as 'code' and it will be much easier for people to make sense of it.

Comment: I tried by adding the CI_REPORTS environment variable where i want to put the reports, but it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Tiffany's response and the link she gave, I think the answer to your question is 'NO. it is not supported at this time'

I'd also echo the recommendation to use 1.8.7  that's what I've been using for a while now and it is working good with watir.

Answer (score 1):

I think most folks are still using ruby 1.8.7 with Watir.  I'm still on 1.8.7, and I use ci_reporter with Watir every day without any problems.

Any chance you can try your code in a 1.8.7 environment?  I just found this blog post that indicates that ci_reporter has not been updated to work with ruby 1.9.2:  http://www.larkware.com/posts/fix-ci-reporter-for-test-unit-2-dot-0

Comment: Thanks Tiffany, Is it possible to manage multiple versions of ruby. As I've got ruby 1.9.2, can i install 1.8.7 and switch to the environment for using ci_reporter.